# Could not debug -Could not run-No debugger set up-Qt5

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, qt4, qt5

I have gbd installed in my OS.
I m running qt5 in linux and when I use the debug option, I get a popup saying  "Could not run" "no debbuger set up" .I could go to Tools > Options > Build and Run > Debugger . All I could see

```
Name                                     Path            Type
auto detected system gdb at usr/bin/gdb  usr/bin/gdb     GDB
```

I even tried adding GDB manually,and I have the gdb at that path but I m getting the same error  when I try to run the debugger "Could not run" "no debbuger set up"

Tools > Options > Build and Run > Kits

[image]

Comment: how did you install Qt?

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center